# W3C document states

Tags: standards, w3c

Within the standards that W3C create, do they have a set of states they go through before they are a standard and **what are those states**?

For example [HTML 5.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/html51/) currently [is in Working Draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/2015/WD-html51-20150506/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The process is typically linked in the section "Status of This Document".

For HTML 5.1, [it says](http://www.w3.org/TR/2015/WD-html51-20150506/):

> This document is governed by the [1 August 2014 W3C Process Document](http://www.w3.org/2014/Process-20140801/).

This links to the [*World Wide Web Consortium Process Document*](http://www.w3.org/2014/Process-20140801/) from 2014-08-01 (the latest version is always accessible from http://www.w3.org/Consortium/Process/).

For technical reports that should become Recommendations, this is [the process](http://www.w3.org/2014/Process-20140801/#recs-and-notes):

> 1. Publication of the [First Public Working Draft](http://www.w3.org/2014/Process-20140801/#first-wd),
> 2. Publication of zero or more revised [Public Working Drafts](http://www.w3.org/2014/Process-20140801/#revised-wd).
> 3. Publication of a [Candidate Recommendation](http://www.w3.org/2014/Process-20140801/#last-call).
> 4. Publication of a [Proposed Recommendation](http://www.w3.org/2014/Process-20140801/#rec-pr).
> 5. Publication as a [W3C Recommendation](http://www.w3.org/2014/Process-20140801/#rec-publication).
> 6. Possibly, Publication as an [Edited Recommendation](http://www.w3.org/2014/Process-20140801/#rec-edited)

However, it’s also possible to go steps back:

> The Director […] *may* require the specification to return to a lower maturity level.

Answer (score 4):

Ahh I think I literally just found the answer on [Consortium/Process](http://www.w3.org/Consortium/Process/Process-19991111/tr.html), too many tabs open!

[The W3C Recommendation track](http://www.w3.org/Consortium/Process/Process-19991111/tr.html#Recs):

> 1. **Working Draft**
>      A Working Draft generally represents work in progress and a commitment by W3C to pursue work in a particular area. The label "Working Draft" does not imply consensus within W3C about the document.
> 2. **Candidate Recommendation**
>      A Candidate Recommendation is a stable Working Draft that the Director has proposed to the community for implementation experience and feedback.
> 3. **Proposed Recommendation**
>      A Proposed Recommendation is a Candidate Recommendation that has benefitted from implementation experience and has been sent to the Advisory Committee for review.
> 4. **Recommendation**
>      A Recommendation reflects consensus within W3C, as represented by the Director's approval. W3C considers that the ideas or technology specified by a Recommendation are appropriate for widespread deployment and promote W3C's mission.