# What do TR and CR stand for in W3C drafts?

Tags: w3c, web-standards

I have seen it in urls:

https://www.w3.org/TR/MathML3/

I have also seen it on [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/#search=css%20var)

[image: CR abbreviation on caniuse.com]

What do the abbreviations **CR** and **TR** stand for in a W3C context?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**TR** (Technical Report) is W3C‘s term/namespace for specifications (or standards), no matter which maturity level they have.

**CR** (Candidate Recommendation) is a maturity level such a specification can have. See [my answer to *W3C document states*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30379968/1591669) for the other levels, and how you can see which process a specification uses (the latest one is always accessible from http://www.w3.org/Consortium/Process/).

#### Example

Let’s use the [HTML5 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/) as example, which uses [the process from 2005-10-14](http://www.w3.org/2005/10/Process-20051014/).

The *W3C Recommendation* is:

```
https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/
```

The *Proposed Recommendation* is:

```
https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/PR-html5-20140916/
```

The *Candidate Recommendation* is:

```
https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/CR-html5-20140731/
```

The latest *Working Draft* is:

```
https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-html5-20140617/
```

As you can see, they are all published in the `/TR/` space, and the maturity level can be seen in the last path segment: `REC`, `PR`, `CR`, `WD`.

Comment: Thank you for the additional abbreviations. I found anotherone myself **LCWD**, which stands for Last Call Working Draft. They sure love their abbreviations, W3C :)

Answer (score 1):

TR = [Technical Report](https://www.w3.org/TR/) (a published standard or draft)

CR = Candidate Recommendation (a stage in the standard development process)

Information on the exact meaning of the terms and the different stages in the technical report development process can be found in the source: [World Wide Web Consortium Process Document](https://www.w3.org/2015/Process-20150901/)

Comment: Tnanks! Does that mean a CR will eventually become a TR when it is a standard? (They usually look quite the same I think)

Comment: @Olov Not necessarily, it might revert back to a previous stage in the process for changes, or be scrapped altogether as work on a TR may stop at any time. The intended path is to Proposed Recommendation, and finally Recommendation. It's all outlined in the document I linked to in the answer.